# How to get the name back and write a csv after using llply in a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, csv, dataframe

I need to add 2 columns to a `list` of csv files and then write the csv's again into a folder. So, what I did is I used `llply`.

```
data_files <- list.files(pattern= ".csv$", recursive = T, full.names = F)
x <- llply(data_files, read.csv, header = T)    
y <- llply(x, within, Cf <- var1 * 8)    
z <- llply(y, within, Pc <- Cf + 1)
```

When I tried to write the files again using `write.table` in a loop:

```
lapply(z, FUN = function(eachPath) {    
  b <- read.csv(eachPath, header = F)      
  write.table(b, file = eachPath, row.names = F, col.names = T, quote = F)    
})
```

I get this error and I think it is because `z` is a list of lists.

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>     'file' must be a character string or connection

What I think it needs to be done is to convert `z` in a list of `dataframes`. I would like and advise of how to do that, plus adding a command to extract the name of each file from a column containing the sample ID.

Thanks